# Can I create Tizen web app with wifi and speech recognition functionality?

Tags: tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-web-app, tizen-web-simulator

I am new to Tizen development. I just want to know whether I can use WIFI manager and speech recognition functionality with web app in tizen. If yes how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, Wifi manager is not available for web app. You can write a native app for accessing wifi manager. If you want to keep your UI in web app, then write hybrid app. Hybrid app has a service in native and UI in web app. You can get/set all wifi info from service app and send those info to UI app through message port. Here is the example of writing hybrid app. Please check

[Sample of Hybrid Service](https://developer.tizen.org/development/sample/native/AppFW/Hybrid_Service)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use **WIFI** manager in web apps.

Here you go

WIFI - https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/web/2.3.0/org.tizen.mobile.web.device.apireference/tizen/systeminfo.html#SystemInfoWifiNetwork

For Speech recognition - You can use JS speech APIs for speech recognition.

More info refer this link and search for "Web Speech" - https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/2.3.1/org.tizen.web.apireference/html/w3c_api/w3c_api_w.html

Comment: Thanks.
My requirement in something different, after clicking on "ON" button in web App, wifi should started automatically and scan for Access Points 
and send frequency and signal strength of Access Points to server.
This can be achived by "Wifi magager" in tizen but as per the link "https://developer.tizen.org/ko/development/dev-guide/2.3.0?langredirect=1"
"Wifi magager" found only under nativ application not under web application.
I don't want to just display Wifi information,So Is there any way to use "Wifi magager" in web application.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Tizen are you using now?

2.4 guide is here.

https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/2.4/org.tizen.web.apireference/html/device_api/mobile/index.html