# Is it possible to programmatically turn on/off/auto the wifi in a wearable web TIZEN app?

Tags: tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-web-app, system-setting

Is it possible to programmatically turn on/off/auto the wifi in a wearable web TIZEN app? Like from a js function in tau.js? I have seen documentation for natively turning on/off, but I didn't find samples/documentation for a web app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, It's not yet. Though you can check the WiFi status from web application, But it's not possible to turn on/off WiFi from Tizen web application yet.

You might like to check [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33241756/can-i-create-tizen-web-app-with-wifi-and-speech-recognition-functionality/37229838#37229838).

Comment: It's been a while. Do you happen to know if anything changed on this subj?

Comment: Doesn't looking like it's gonna be available for the Web API.... no progress yet on this platform.
But now there's API for .NET C# along with Native C/C++
https://docs.tizen.org/application/dotnet/guides/connectivity/wifi/
https://docs.tizen.org/application/native/guides/connectivity/wifi/